# Should WSO2 Server Registry Indexing be turned off if G-Reg is used?

Tags: indexing, wso2, wso2-governance-registry

WSO2 server will perform registry indexing when it is started (or with some delay). The database connections will be used up during the indexing. This causes the deployment of multiple instances of WSO2 server (either EI, APIM) to be difficult due to insufficient connections in the RDBMS (eg PostgreSQL and MySQL can support up to 300 connections).

During the research, I found WSO2 Governance Registry (G-Reg) which allows the WSO2 servers to mount the config and gov registry with G-Reg. My questions is, if the registry of WSO2 servers are mounted to G-Reg, should the registry indexing at the WSO2 servers be turned off? Is there any impact on the performance of the WSo2 servers?

Thank you.